# Is there is any way to get the purchase details with Email ID through In-app purchase flutter in android and IOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, hybrid-mobile-app

we have integrated In-app purchases in flutter using this "in_app_purchase: ^3.0.7" package everything is working fine. Still, our application is something anybody can use without login or Sign-up, so here we are facing the issue we need to store the purchase details in the DB but to do that we need to pass the Email ID from which account it has been purchased. Still, we cannot get a solution for this issue, so if there is any way to achieve this, please add your answers here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can ask your users to optionally create an account. Explain that creating an account is not required, but if they do so then they will be able to access their purchases on other devices. If they do not then their purchases are limited to this device and could be lost.

Comment: Why do you need an email address to store purchase details in the DB?

Comment: I also need this answer.